# Excel VBA is converting my ‘™’ (Trademark TM) in my XML to ‘T’ when I run an XSLT which converts UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xslt

I have the following XSLT to take an XML encoded UTF-8, that was originally created from Excel, and create the same XML but encode ISO-8859-1

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works well and when I use XMLspy to run the transform the `™` becomes `&#8482` which is great. The issue I have is when I use the following Excel VBA, thank you Parfait, to run the XSLT the `™` in the XML becomes `T`.

```
Set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set xsldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set newdoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

'LOAD XML
xmldoc.async = False
xmldoc.Load “path and file name & fileName.xml"

'LOAD XSL
xsldoc.async = False
xsldoc.Load "path and file name.xslt"

'TRANSFORM
xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xsldoc, newdoc
newdoc.Save “Path and file name.xml"
```

I don’t understand why when Excel runs the XSLT the results are different. I originally research if the Excel could export XML encoded ISO-8859-1 in the first place but that does not seem to be an option.

Comment: Don't know how encoding works in VBA, but maybe you can try to replace the trademark sign to something that you can convert back later.